# How to merge screw with model

Tags: modifiers, stl

This is my first model using blender and I am preparing the model for 3d printing so I am currently using booleans to combine objects. Things went pretty smooth until I got to this 'wrap' that I made by following a video. How can I merge this wrap I made (using the screw modifier) to the model? Maybe this is not enough info so let me know what else you need. I can share the model also if that would help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can use a Boolean modifier but it looks like you have given thickness to your handle, therefore you'll have inner faces, which is not good for 3D printing

Comment: I did use thickness. How else would you suggest I do this? I'm learning and just followed a youtube video which seems to have worked well for a visual model but I guess not great for 3d printing.

Comment: I don't know how you did the screw part but you need to redo it without thickness

Comment: It might be helpful if you uploaded the blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post that link in the question.